# Excel vba onkey with a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I require your help with the following please:

1. I need to run existing macros by pressing shortcut keys.
2. Shortcut key to define is: Shift + Control + (a number from 1 to
   30).
3. Column B contains numbers from 1 to 30 in the following range,
   B14=1, B15=2.... B43=30.
4. Column E contains the names of the macros, for example
   E14=MacroA, E15=MacroB.... E43=MacroAD.
5. Consequently, by pressing Shift + Control + 10 the MacroJ should
   be run.

I've done the following code but no luck:

```
Sub test()

    Dim n As Integer

    For n = 1 To 30

    Dim macroname As String

    macroname = Application.VLOOKUP(n, Range("B14:E43"), 4, false).Value

    Application.OnKey "+^n","macroname"

End Sub
```

Comment: you forgot a `next n` , before `end sub` , and `dim macroname` should be before the `for n` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close!
 The code would "almost" work if you had a macro like:

```
Sub macroname()
    MsgBox "Hello world"
End Sub
```

You need a syntax like:

```
Dim s1 As String
s1 = "+^" & CStr(n)
Application.OnKey s1, macroname
```

I don't know if **n** can exceed **9**